"Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found", Tensorflow in VScode
So I'm trying to start machine learning and I've been following the tensorflow installation guide from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip. When I run the command:
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

In Ananconda prompt, it seems to work fine returning:
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')].
Now I want to work on projects in VScode, but when I run the same code I get the error "Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found" for various different files. I have my Conda environment selected as the interpreter, but I'm not sure if there some other setup issue as I am pretty new to programming in general.

Have you selected and activated the same python environment you tested outside vscode in - i.e. from the command palette select "Python: Select Interpreter" and the "Python: Create Terminal"

@DavidWaterworth Hi David. The Python interpreter is set to the same conda environment, but I'm not sure what terminal I'm looking for. Selecting Create Terminal just switches terminal from powershell to python

In theory "Create Terminal" should activate the selected python interpreter - so once activated you should be able to run "python" and get the selected conda environment. There are setting that disable this and I'm more familiar with vscode on linux or macos though.
